# miniget status code 416 when playing music with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

im writing a  few utility/music bots for a discord server im in but about half way through the song it stops playing and in the terminal it says (please ignore the poor code im new do this but im extremely enthusiastic)

```js
 Error: input stream: Status code: 416
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Comrade Nicolai\node_modules\miniget\dist\index.js:156:27)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:603:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:476:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:268:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
```

anyone know how i can fix this?

heres my code if it helps:

```
//the constants that make the whole thing work//
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const RichEmbed = require('discord.js');
    const bot = new Discord.Client();
    const bot2 = new Discord.Client();
    const token = '';
    const token2 = '';
    const PREFIX = '!';
    const PREFIX2 = '.';  
    const cheerio = require('cheerio');
    const request = require('request');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const ms = require('ms');
    const nbx = require('noblox.js');
    const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");

    const queue = new Map();


        //command files manager//
    bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();

    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }


    // ready messages// 
    bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Nicolai reporting for duty');
    })
    bot2.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Mr Syldavia are you secure');
    })






    //comrade nicolai commands//
    //prefix checker//
    bot.on('message', message=>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    //commands//


    switch(args[0]){
    case "ping":
    bot.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    break;
    case "play":
    execute(message, serverQueue);
    break;
    case "skip":
    skip(message, serverQueue);
    break;
    case "stop":
     stop(message, serverQueue);
     break;

    

   //help command//
    case 'cmds':
    bot.commands.get('im not sure yet').execute(message, args);
     break;
        
        
    case 'help':
    bot.commands.get('help').execute(message, args);
    break;
        

            
    }

   })

      //mr syldavia commands//
         //prefix checker//
        bot2.on('message', message=>{
       if(!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX2)) return;

        let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX2.length).split(" ");
       //commands//


           switch(args[0]){
        case "ping":
         if (!message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Moderator")) return 
        message.channel.send('You do do not have permission to do that!')
       bot.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
           break;

    

          //help command//
         case 'cmds':
              if (!message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Moderator")) return 
             message.channel.send('You do do 
            not have permission to do that!')
            bot.commands.get('im not sure yet').execute(message, args);
         break;
        
        
          case 'help':
         if (!message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Moderator")) return 
            message.channel.send('You do do 
           not have permission to do that!')
          bot.commands.get('help').execute(message, args);
     break;
        
        
        //create poll command//
       case 'poll':
                if (!message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Moderator")) return 
            message.channel.send('You do do 
            not have permission to do that!')
           bot.commands.get('poll command').execute(message, args);
         break;
           

                  // create announcement command//
          case 'announcement':
      if (!message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Moderator")) return 
           message.channel.send('You do do 
            not have permission to do that!')
            bot.commands.get('poll').execute(message, args);
           break;

             case 'iannouncement':
         if (!message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Moderator")) return 
        message.channel.send('You do do 
           not have permission to do that!')
                       bot.commands.get('iannouncement').execute(message, args);
     break;

      case 'clear':
      if (!message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Moderator")) return 
          message.channel.send('You do do 
      not have permission to do that!')
    let msgArgs = args.slice(1).join(" ");            
    message.channel.bulkDelete(msgArgs)
   .then(messages => message.channel.send(`Bulk deleted ${messages.size} messages`))            
     .then(msg => msg.delete({timeout: 1000})); 
                
      break;

            
      }
    })


     async function execute(message, serverQueue) {
      const args = message.content.split(" ");

      const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
      if (!voiceChannel)
      return message.channel.send(
       "You need to be in a voice channel to play music!"
       );
      const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
      if (!permissions.has("CONNECT") || !permissions.has("SPEAK")) {

         }

    const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);
    const song = {
    title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
     url: songInfo.videoDetails.video_url
      };

    if (!serverQueue) {
    const queueContruct = {
      textChannel: message.channel,
        voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
       connection: null,
      songs: [],
        volume: 5,
       playing: true
      };

     queue.set(message.guild.id, queueContruct);

     queueContruct.songs.push(song);

       try {
      var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
        queueContruct.connection = connection;
      play(message.guild, queueContruct.songs[0]);
     } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      queue.delete(message.guild.id);
         return message.channel.send(err);
     }
     } else {
     serverQueue.songs.push(song);
       return message.channel.send(`${song.title} has been added to the queue!`);
    }
    }

       function skip(message, serverQueue) {
       if (!message.member.voice.channel)
         return message.channel.send(
          "You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!"
        );
       if (!serverQueue)
        return message.channel.send("There is no song that I could skip!");
       serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.finish();
      }

      function stop(message, serverQueue) {
        if (!message.member.voice.channel)
         return message.channel.send(
         "You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!"
        );
        serverQueue.songs = [];
       serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
         }

        function play(guild, song) {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
     if (!song) {
      serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
      queue.delete(guild.id);
      return;
    }

   const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
     .play(ytdl(song.url))
    .on("finish", () => {
      serverQueue.songs.shift();
      play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
      })
      .on("error", error => console.error(error));
      dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
      serverQueue.textChannel.send(`Start playing: **${song.title}**`);
    }
    //idk the point of this i just know i need it//
    bot2.login(token2);
    bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, it's because you're playing a video when all you need is the audio. You can fix this by making a filter 'options' in the play() function which gives you audio instead of video. So instead you'll do .play(ytdl(song.url, options))

```
const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
options = {
  quality: 'highestaudio'
};
 .play(ytdl(song.url, options))
```

Comment: thank you soo much!, ive been trying to figure this out for days i could not figure it out to save my life